# Reverse order of string inside brackets in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a neat way to reverse the string inside a certain type of brackets in vim, for instance

```
{1,2,3,4,5}

=>

{5,4,3,2,1}
```

?

Answer (score 7):

How about this command?

```
:%s/{\zs\\(.\\{-}\\)\ze}/\= join(reverse(split(submatch(0), '\zs')), '')/g
```

Comment: Using very magic to avoid too many backslashes `>%s/{\v\zs([^}]+)\ze}/\=join(reverse(split(submatch(1),'.\zs')),'')/g`

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to utilize the `append` feature of register by using upper-case register name.

To achieve this, you have to do some preparations:

- clean `"a` register: `:let @a=""`
- add a comma before the first element: `{,1,2,3,4,5}`
- put the cursor under `}` in normal mode

Ok, here we go:

- execute `"AdF,`, and press `.` to repeat until all elements are deleted.
- execute `"aP` to paste the reversed sequence, you will get: `{,5,4,3,2,1}`
- delete the first comma

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```
:.s/\v(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)/\5,\4,\3,\2,\1
```